# figure with program, caption prefix and dedicated list

Tags: floats, program

I am using the `program` package for illustrating algorithms in my document, which I currently put into a `figure` environment. Now I want to have a dedicated list of algorithms in my document and not mix them with the rest of figures. Also, I would like to change the caption title from *Figure X: ...* to *Algorithm X: ...* Do you have any hints how to achieve this?

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrbook}
\usepackage{program}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \begin{program}
        a=a+1;
    \end{program}
    \caption{Example code}
    \label{alg:exampleCode}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an idea.

Load the `algorithm` package and encase your `program`s in `algorithm`s environments instead of `figure`s.

The command `\listofalgorithms` gives you the desired list.

MWE

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrbook}
\usepackage{program}
\usepackage[plain]{algorithm}

\begin{document}

\listofalgorithms
\vspace{3cm}

\begin{algorithm}
    \begin{program}
        a=a+1;
    \end{program}
    \caption{Example code}
    \label{alg:exampleCode}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Perfect, so simple, thank you! Didn't know that this could be combined with `program`.